# sbt/ivy version ranges does not resolve but exact versions do

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I can't seem to get SBT to resolve my dependencies when I use the range syntax.

So

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  //exact version works i.e.     0.5.3+27
  //but what we want to work is  [0.5.3,)
  //or I've since moved the build number to the 4th component  0.5.3.+
  "company"                %% "project"      % "0.5.3.+",
  //...
)
```

I can get exact versions to work fine, but none of the version syntax specified at 
https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/ivyfile/dependency.html#revision
or the examples on http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html work.

I've looked around and found there was a fix for something like this here https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/2075 which went into sbt `0.13.9`, I'm using `0.13.11`.

The first version range is what I was using because of what Semantic version recommends for meta data in point [10](http://semver.org/#spec-item-10) when that didn't work, the library [management docs / Ivy revision docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html) says "end the revision with a + selects the latest sub-revision of the dependency module", so I removed the + in case that was causing a problem and added the 4th component which is just the build number GoCD provides. Again exact version works but not sub-revisions.

In sbt I can see URL of the two formats being hit:

1. https://dl.bintray.com/`<username>`/internal-releases/`<namespace>`/`<project-name>`_2.11/`[revision]`/`<project-name>`_2.11-[revision].pom
2. http://dl.bintray.com/`<username>`/internal-releases/`<namespace>`/`<project-name>`_2.11/`[revision]`/ivys/ivy.xml

Note here `[revision]` is what is literally in the URL printed. The things in angle brackets are my replacements. Hence why I thought [issue 2005](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/2075) was related.
I don't have an SBT repositories file.

So for the question, have I been doing something wrong in the above, how do I get version range work with the `min.minor.patch.build` syntax i.e. `0.x.x.+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked around this.
Bintray directory listings doesn't have valid HTTP links (anti-crawler effort on Binary's part.) As a result the Ivy resolver fails to fetch the list of published versions.

Using the maven layout instead of Ivy's works out because Maven format includes a metadata.xml which lists all available versions.
So the work around is to republish libs using the maven layout instead of Ivy's to get this meta data.